# How i can init kubeadm on containerd or cri-docker?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines, kubernetes, proxmox

`kubectl version --client`

> `Client Version: v1.28.1
> Customize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3`

`kubeadm version`

> `kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"28", GitVersion:"v1.28.1", GitCommit:"8dc49c4b984b897d423aab4971090e1879eb4f23", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-08-24T11 :21:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.20.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Versions eliminate the problem described in this block:

> kubeadm will not install or manage kubelet or kubectl for you, so you will need to ensure they match the version of the Kubernetes control plane you want kubeadm to install for you. If you do not, there is a risk of a version skew occurring that can lead to unexpected, buggy behavior. However, one minor version skew between the kubelet and the control plane is supported, but the kubelet version may never exceed the API server version. For example, the kubelet running 1.7.0 should be fully compatible with a 1.8.0 API server, but not vice versa.

It was installed on a proxmox virtual machine with an ubuntu server 22.04.3 minimized system.

Unfortunately, k8s does not ping without VPN, so VPN is enabled on the host, WireGuard.
Configured masquerade in NAT.

I installed everything according to the documentation, installed cri-docker as it is written there, I run it with the command: `kubeadm init --v=5 --cri-socket=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock`

When starting without an explicitly specified socket, I get an error, I have 2 of them (containerd and cri-docker), as I understood from the cri-docker instructions, it should be selected by default.

Output when using cri-dockerd:

`[kubelet-check] The HTTP call equal to 'curl -sSL http://localhost:10248/healthz' failed with error: Get "http:// localhost:10248/healthz": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: connect: connection refused.`

Output after kubeadm reset --v=5 --cri-socker=unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock and kubeadm init --v=5 --cri-socket=unix: ///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock:

`[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred: [ERROR CRI]: container runtime is not running: output: time="2023-09-07T15:56:59Z" level=fatal msg="validate service connection: validate CRI v1 runtime API for endpoint \"unix:/// var/run/containerd/containerd.sock\": rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = unknown service runtime.v1.RuntimeService" , error: exit status 1`

What is the error and how to fix it?

In google same problems, but have no answers

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by doing what is written in this tutorial :
https://www.jjworld.fr/kubernetes-installation/

Comment: Please add the info from that link into this post to make it a complete answer. Leave the link for attribution, but if that site changes, the answer will be lost, and for that reason it is best to have all that info right here.